# RTF to Plain Text

Tags: php, rtf

I'm trying to find a 'free' RTF to plain text converter for PHP. Does anyone know of a good one? All of the ones Google found don't work.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations aren't allowed here, but they are on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [this link](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_the_clean_text_from_rtf.php)? Found it on Google.

I have tried it using a RTF file made by OpenOffice, and it works. It can extract the texts from RTF file, but some special characters are wrongly encoded. Or, am I missing? What did you mean of "plain text"?

Answer (score 2):

I tried several solutions for similar issue, the only one I found wich was working in my case is this one : https://github.com/silvermine/php-rtflex

Hope this helps.