# Convert RTF to Plain text Array

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = "
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs18\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch <- MBisono--2/13/2015 12:01:25 PM ->}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch How are you? Hope all is well.  Just wanted to drop you a note that our benefits seem to be getting screwed up every time we have a new employee or if someone changes something. We have certain rules set up for Class 1 and Class 2 and it does not seem like the benefits dept is following them. }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch  }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch Payroll is great we love Christine. It just seems like there is always something wrong with our benefits.}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch  }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch Alexis}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch  }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch Met with Admin and Benefits to discuss MAcGuffin's benefits.  Admin has had no issues, Benefits advised that recently an employee was set up with contributions, when it should have been 100% employer paid. }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
}
}";
```

I have an RTF string like the one above.  How can I convert this into a plain string?  I would like it to be it an array like this.

```
array(
    '<- MBisono--2/13/2015 12:01:25 PM ->',
    'How are you? Hope all is well.  Just wanted to drop you a note that our benefits seem to be getting screwed up every time we have a new employee or if someone changes something. We have certain rules set up for Class 1 and Class 2 and it does not seem like the benefits dept is following them.',
    'Payroll is great we love Christine. It just seems like there is always something wrong with our benefits.',
    'Alexis',
    'Met with Admin and Benefits to discuss MAcGuffin\'s benefits.  Admin has had no issues, Benefits advised that recently an employee was set up with contributions, when it should have been 100% employer paid.'
)
```

The string always starts with "\ltrch" and ends with "}\li0".  Hope that helps. Thank you regex pros!

Comment: Perhaps you can find an answer here, through google: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_the_clean_text_from_rtf.php which may be found in an answer from stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273937/rtf-to-plain-text : From these functions, you can firstly split every single part of your string and convert it to plain text... Or maybe you can directly use this.. http://sourceforge.net/projects/phprtf/

Comment: Have you tried anything? It doesn't appear so.

Comment: @l'L'l, I tried using preg_replace.  I only have to get rid of the string starting with the backslash \.  So far I only got up to this,
    preg_replace("/\\/", "", $input_lines);
But it only removed the backslash and not the string afterwards

Comment: You'll need to include the other elements you want or not in your regex; that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiat with RTF, but I have designed a snippet tailored to your input.

Store the substrings that precede and follow your targeted substrings, then prepare them for the regex engine by escaping backslashes and then demand that special characters are treated literally in the regex by calling `preg_quote()`.

The `\S` requires matches to start with a non-whitspace character -- this omits the empty lines.

`\s*` after the capture group acts to `rtrim()` any unwanted trailing spaces.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HW0mX))

```
$string = <<<'TEXT'
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs18\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch <- MBisono--2/13/2015 12:01:25 PM ->}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch How are you? Hope all is well.  Just wanted to drop you a note that our benefits seem to be getting screwed up every time we have a new employee or if someone changes something. We have certain rules set up for Class 1 and Class 2 and it does not seem like the benefits dept is following them. }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch  }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch Payroll is great we love Christine. It just seems like there is always something wrong with our benefits.}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch  }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch Alexis}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch  }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f2\cf2 {\ltrch Met with Admin and Benefits to discuss MAcGuffin's benefits.  Admin has had no issues, Benefits advised that recently an employee was set up with contributions, when it should have been 100% employer paid. }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
}
}
TEXT;

$start = preg_quote(addcslashes('{\ltrch ', '//'), '/');
$end = preg_quote(addcslashes('}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}', '//'), '/');
var_export(
    preg_match_all(
        "/$start(\S.*?)\s*$end/",
        $string,
        $matches
    )
    ? $matches[1]
    : 'no matches'
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '<- MBisono--2/13/2015 12:01:25 PM ->',
  1 => 'How are you? Hope all is well.  Just wanted to drop you a note that our benefits seem to be getting screwed up every time we have a new employee or if someone changes something. We have certain rules set up for Class 1 and Class 2 and it does not seem like the benefits dept is following them.',
  2 => 'Payroll is great we love Christine. It just seems like there is always something wrong with our benefits.',
  3 => 'Alexis',
  4 => 'Met with Admin and Benefits to discuss MAcGuffin\'s benefits.  Admin has had no issues, Benefits advised that recently an employee was set up with contributions, when it should have been 100% employer paid.',
)
```

If `\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par` is variable text, you can just remove that portion from the `$end` declaration.